# How to verify the line starts with a number while reading variable line by line in shell

Tags: shell

I got the contents between two strings in a variable which contains multiple lines.
I want to check whether each line starts with a number and if so I will increment a counter and also need string after that number and before the next number.
Say I have a variable $line which contains:

```
1. Create
    create a volume.
2. destroy 
      destroy a volume.
```

and so on.
I want to get the count say 10 operations in var1 , string after number in var2 and text after create,destroy (so on) in var3.
How to handle in shell script.
Thanks in advance

Adding Code :

```
line=$(sed -n '/Description/,/properties/p'    readme.txt)
echo "$line"



sed -n -e '/^[0-9]/{s/\([0-9]*\).*/\1/;h;n;s/^ *//;H;x;s/\n/ /p;d;}' <<< "$line"
operations=0
while read -r n str ;
do
    let operations+=1
    printf '%d, %d, %s\n' "$operations" "$n" "$str"
done < <(sed -n -e '/^[0-9]/{s/\([0-9]*\).*/\1/;h;n;s/^ *//;H;x;s/\n/ /;p;d;}'  <<<"$line")


printf "Opertions = %d\n' "$operations"
done
```

Where $line contains contents between Description and properties on which I have to do the required operations.

Comment: Is it always exactly one line between the numbered lines?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly then you want something like this (note that I presume you are using `bash` for some things below, if this is not the case it would have to be modified somewhat).

First, get the bulleted number plus the string on the next line. A little `sed` will do it.

```
sed -n -e '/^[0-9]/{s/\([0-9]*\).*/\1/;h;n;s/^ *//;H;x;s/\n/ /p;d;}' <<<"$line"
```

Next we just need to read the lines, count the lines and store them in variables.

```
operations=0
while read -r n str ; do
    let operations+=1
    printf '%d, %d, %s\n' "$operations" "$n" "$str"
done < <(sed -n -e '/^[0-9]/{s/\([0-9]*\).*/\1/;h;n;s/^ *//;H;x;s/\n/ /;p;d;}' <<<"$line")

printf 'Opertions = %d\n' "$operations"
```

During each loop `n` is the number from the bullet and `str` is the string from the following line.

Comment: Thanks Sorpigal but its throwing error: txthtml1: line 17: syntax error near unexpected token `<'
txthtml1: line 17: `done < <(sed -n -e '/^[0-9]/{s/\([0-9]*\).*/\1/;h;n;s/^ *//;H;x;s/\n/ /;p;d;}' <<<"$line")'

Comment: @user1389673: I presumed your shell was bash, but this means that it isn't (or it's a very old version). You can work around this by running the `sed` command on a separate line and directing the output in to a file, then replacing the `<()` construct with the file name.